# Python request module can't find data attribute on website

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to request a specific data attribute in a public website using the **Requests** and **BeautifulSoup** modules in python. The data attribute in the  tag on the website has no value but I thought I could request it using the *title* part of my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://www.oneplus.com/ca_en/oneplus-7pro?from=op7pro_header'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(attrs={"data-v-5b5a108c": True})

print(title)
```

When I request the parent  tag with a data attribute that has a value, the  tag that I'm looking for just doesn't appear. Why can't I see it? Am I crazy or is this not how it works?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML elements on this page are created dynamically, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see them. But the data is stored in Json format inside the page:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.oneplus.com/ca_en/oneplus-7pro?from=op7pro_header'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

data = json.loads(soup.select_one('#data-device').contents[0])

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data['steps']['options'][0]['label'])
```

Prints:

```
Mirror Gray
```